# Converting circular structure to json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've my js function that takes data from a form

```
 var dataUpload={};

             dataUpload.p1=$('#p1').combodate('getValue'); //date
             dataUpload.p2=$('#p2').combodate('getValue');//date
             dataUpload.p3=$('#p3').val();                //textarea
             dataUpload.p4=$('#p4').val();                //text input
             dataUpload.p5=Date.now();                    //date  
             dataUpload.p6=1;                             //number
             dataUpload.id=Id;                              //number
           $http.post("url of your route",data).success(function (data)
           {
              console.log("success");
           });
```

in the first time it gives **"Converting circular structure to json"** error, the second times it insert the data without problems.
I cannot understand its problem : why it happens like this ?

Comment: What is `id_paziente` ?

Comment: this is a form which its data has to go in a insert into query. it's the id of the patient. but I've found the solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution :
A normal **$http post** or every **http method** function, sends the data with the choosen method in a **json format**.
AngularJs applies toJson() function when sending the data.
If one part of the data contains an object which json cannot convert, it will fire the **'Converting circular structure to json in angularjs'** error.
If you send it a second time Angularjs tries to evaluate the object and it is successful, so the query is then executed.

```
Date.now()                                                
dataUpload.p2=$('#p2').combodate('getValue');//date xeditable
```

they both could return an object.
So if you encounter this error, check every value of your data that you are sending, they could not be what you think they should be (I expect to have string and it returns me an Object instead).
You can understand if your data is an object with console.log :

```
console.log(data1);  //output : Object obj                             IS AN OBJECT
console.log(data2);  //output : "Answer about it"                      IT'S NOT AN OBJECT
```

If the output is like ***data1*** Then you have to format your data into the form you desire with methods like `moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")` or using other libraries